# GAE: Managed VMs - Suporte ao Java 8

Tags: java, google-app-engine

> **[rant mode on]**
>
> Já faz um tempinho que a comunidade está pedindo [suporte ao Java 8](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537) no GAE. Esse mês o suporte público oficial da Oracle ao Java 7 [acaba](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml). Parece que não haverá mudanças do lado no GAE antes do fim do ciclo de vida do Java 7.
>
> Além disso o container de servlets do GAE continua na versão 2.5. Existe um [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091) aberto fazem 5 anos, e nada da Google atualizar o Jetty do GAE para suportar versões mais modernas da especificação (3.0, 3.1, etc). Dessa forma, pelo menos no que se refere à solução de PaaS já podemos considerar que a stack suportada pelo GAE é legada.
>
> **[rant mode off]**

Eu possuo algumas aplicações que precisam de evolução. Essas aplicações hoje dependem fortemente de serviços da Google como o datastore, task queue, etc. A sugestão da Google para desenvolvedores nessa situação é migrar seu ambiente para [Custom Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/), um meio termo entre PaaS e IaaS no estilo do [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

Dito isso, não encontrei nenhuma documentação ou post indicando como utilizar as Managed VMs do GAE com Java 8 (de preferência em um container moderno). Aparentemente isso envolveria um `Dockerfile`com as dependências aos serviços do GAE + stack do Java.

Alguém que já tenha trilhado esse caminho do Java 8 no GAE com Managed VMs poderia dar uma luz sobre como colocar um ambiente para rodar (assumindo que isso seja possível)?

Uma idéia daquilo que é necessário para materializar o ambiente + um `Dockerfile` de exemplo viriam muito a calhar.